# Give pthread_setschedparam() permissions to non-root user (linux)

Tags: linux, scheduling, threads, posix

How can I give a non-root user permission to execute pthread_setschedparam() to set thread priorities?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Grant the [`CAP_SYS_NICE`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) capability.

This can be done either by user or by application as explained here:

[How to set CAP_SYS_NICE capability to a Linux user? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635515/how-to-set-cap-sys-nice-capability-to-a-linux-user)

Comment: +1. Extending the answer with how to do it would be awesome.

Comment: It turns out this is far from trivial.